# Magento 2: Show Category name below product name in the product page

Tags: product, grid-layout

[image]

I want to show Category name below the product name

here is the code:

```
<div class="block widget block-products-list <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
    <?php if ($block->getTitle()) : ?>
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getTitle())) ?></strong>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
        <div class="products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?> <?= /* @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
            <ol class="product-items <?= /* @noEscape */ $type ?>">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                    <div class="product-item-info">
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                            <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-item-details">
                            <strong class="product-item-name">
                                <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                   href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                   class="product-item-link">
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <?php if ($templateType) : ?>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type) ?>

                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item) ?>

                            <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart) : ?>
                                <div class="product-item-inner">
                                    <div class="product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart) : ?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_item); ?>
                                                    <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>" method="post">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($postParams['data']['product']) ?>">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                                        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                        <button type="submit"
                                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                <?php else : ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php else : ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way ..

There are 2 ways to get category Data:

**=> Using Object Manager:**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentCategory = $registry->registry('current_category');
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
echo $currentCategory->getUrl() ;
```

**=> Using Block :**

**1) Create Block:**

> app/code/Jaydip/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Jaydip\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
?>
```

**2) Get current category in any template (.phtml) file**

```
// print current category data
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
```

**Other steps are you can call phtml file in Theme and layout**

/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
                   name="product.info.category.name"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/categoryName.phtml" after="page.main.title"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/categoryName.phtml

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
        echo $cat->getName();
    }

?>
```